# jqgrid editoptions: required not functioning

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

ok not sure what i'm doing wrong here:

```
            $("#list").jqGrid({
            url: --URL--,
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            colModel: [
              { label: 'Index', index: 'Index', key: true, hidden: true },
              { label: 'SampleSize', index: 'SampleSize', editable: true, editrules: { required: true, number: true} },
            ],
            pager: '#pager',
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            viewrecords: true,
            height: 'auto',
            width: 'auto',
            editurl: '.',
            createurl: '.',
            deleteurl: '.'
        });

        $('#list').jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager',
            { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: false },
            { url: '#' }, // edit options
            {url: '#' }, // add options
            {url: '#' }, // delete options
            {}, // search options
            {}
        );
```

when editing / creating a record, i can keep the textbox for 'samplesize' empty and jqgrid does not throw any kind of error. am i forgetting to add something in?

Comment: you may be confusing it because you're flagging both number and required? (a blank value isn't a number). I don't know for sure but I find a lot of strangeness in using jqGrid myself.

Comment: yes good point! i did try removing the number bit tho.. and still didn't work. i agree i'm having a few other issues with the plugin as well.. such a shame because it seems so good!

Comment: I find also a lot of strange things in the example. I can add that there are no `createurl` and `deleteurl` parameters of jqGrid and the url '.' which will be overwritten with '#' looks at least very strange.

Comment: although it has nothing to do with the problem i was having, I would remove the url: '#' parts, and change the editurl etc to '#' instead of '.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok found out the problem - i didn't have the 'name' parameter in the colModel:

```
        $("#list").jqGrid({
        url: --URL--,
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colModel: [
          { label: 'Index', index: 'Index', key: true, hidden: true },
          { name: 'SampleSize', label: 'SampleSize', index: 'SampleSize', editable: true, editrules: { required: true, number: true}
```

easy fix when you know how...